# How to search multiple tables at the same time in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm tying to design a Sign In page. I have three tables `students`, `professors`, `dean`. I want to fetch the password for the given username and check if it's correct. I can do this for one table with :

```
def get_password_by_username(username):
    c.execute("SELECT password FROM students WHERE username = :username", {"username": username})
    return c.fetchone()
```

How can I search for the username in all three tables at the same time?
thanks.

Comment: Use `join` in sql

Comment: @bigbounty I already looked it up but couldn't understand how it works. could you please show me a code that uses `join` for my question?

Comment: Are you sure you want to search for "username in all three tables"?

Comment: Having a single `users` table with a column that contains the user's type (student/prof/dean) might be an easier design to work with.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks but I got tons of different data for each student/prof/dean. I can't put them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT username, password FROM students 
UNION ALL
SELECT username, password FROM professors
UNION ALL
SELECT username, password FROM dean
```

returns all the usernames and passwords from the 3 tables and you can filter to get the password like this:

```
SELECT password
FROM (
  SELECT username, password FROM students 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT username, password FROM professors
  UNION ALL
  SELECT username, password FROM dean
)
WHERE username = :username
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the data associated with some student based on student's `username`, you should use `JOIN` in your SQL queries to achieve that. You will maybe have to redesign your database a little bit to be able to get all the data you need.

There are plenty of nice guides around about how to use `JOIN` ([this one](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/) or [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)), read them to understand better how to join your tables in a desired way.

Very simple example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    students s
LEFT JOIN professors p 
    ON s.professorID = p.professorID
WHERE
    s.username = 'some_username';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them with a comma

```
def get_password_by_username(username):
    c.execute("SELECT password FROM students, professors, dean WHERE username=?", (username,)
    return c.fetchone()
```

Comment: every single one works but with commas I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: password` :(

Comment: @ladypary I can't see `name` in your code, but you can assign a variable to a query with `?`. i.e `WHERE name=?, (your_variable,)`

Comment: `WHERE username =? ", (username,)` this also doesn't work! there is not a single `name` in my whole py file!

Comment: thanks for your effort but are you sure about this syntax?  `c.execute("SELECT password FROM students WHERE username=?", (username,)` works perfectly fine as  well as `dean` and `professors` alone. but together I get an error.